# Looking for tips on integrating TinyMCE Image Manager with S3 or Rackspace CloudFiles

Tags: amazon-s3, tinymce, cloudfiles

We are moving away from using a local file system for all our media and moving it over to Cloud Files (Rackspace).  The downer is that we use the ImageManager plugin which seems to rely heavily on doing filesystem commands to generate lists of files etc.

Have any of you had experience with using TinyMCE and inserting images and assets from a cloud storage service?